# the relationship between styled component and less preprocessor

Tags: reactjs, less, styled-components

recently i learn that if i want to use '&:hover` in the .css files,
i have to use less preprocessor.

in styled component, we can use `&:hover` in code.
so my question is that

- whether react use less preprocessor inside ?

here is the source code

```
const example = styled.div`
  span {
    font-size: 36px;
    &:hover { 
      font-size: 100px;
    }
  }
`;
```

i want to know details how react code compile with less preprocessor.

Comment: No styled components has a different syntax than less. The `&` operator exists in both but that's basically the only similarity, the two are entirely different. Even how the `&` operator works is completely different

Answer (score 0):

As described in [styled-components docs about nesting](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting):

> The preprocessor we use, stylis, supports scss-like syntax for automatically nesting styles.

React itself does not perform any special CSS preprocessing.

Styled-components does, but not according to Less.